# When I accidentally break wudu, what should I do?

Tags: sharia, wudu

When I do wudu or pray, but accidentally breaking wudu. I know I have to do wudu again... I want to know that should I go to toilet first before wudu? Should I do wudu first before I pray?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know that should I go to toilet first before wudu?

The purpose of going to toilet is to empty the body of urine or solid waste and to clean the private areas of the body from where the waste exits. If you do not have a need to empty your body from waste or clean the private areas then you do not have to go to the toilet before wudu.

> Should I do wudu first before I pray?

Yes, a prayer (salat) without wudu is void. You have to be in the state of wudu in order to do prayers (salat).

Answer (score 0):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

In regard to your question that asked

> When I accidentally break wudu, what should I do?

First of all, you should go to clean (wash) the part which has got Najis or … as the initial practice, afterwards, you go and repeat your Wudu (again)(re-Wudu), then you can go to say your prayers (Salah). Otherwise your prayer won't be accepted in case you say your prayer with a broken Wudu.

And Allah knows best